# Using time series NDVI from Sentinel-2 L1C (TOA) product

Tags: ndvi, sentinel

I am working on getting time series NDVI data from Sentinel-2 L1C, since it is available before Sentinel-2 L2A.

Is it ok to use L1C product or I need to use L2A to develop time series NDVI?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the [SENTINEL-2 Level-2A](https://sentinels.copernicus.eu/web/sentinel/technical-guides/sentinel-2-msi/level-2a/algorithm) guideline, there are tools that you can use to generate Level 2A Bottom of Atmosphere (BOA) from Sentinel-2 L1C Top of Atmosphere (TOA).

From the above link, it says:

> **Level-2A** can also be **generated by the User** from the Level-1C product
> using the Sentinel-2 Toolbox or the standalone version of the Sen2Cor
> processor.

You can use [Sen2Cor](http://step.esa.int/main/snap-supported-plugins/sen2cor/) to generate SENTINEL-2 Level-2A and then calculate the NDVI for the target area. In this case, the NDVI images will be consistent among the time series images.